# How can I make sure my OpenCL code works correctly on different graphic cards?

Tags: gpu, testing, gpgpu

I'm testing on adding some OpenCL code in my game, but I only have a single Nvidia card & I'm not sure the code will run normally on other platforms.

Is there any way to make sure my code runs as expected on different graphic cards without having direct access to the hardware myself?